# Help with Zen Painting translation?

Tags: translation, character-identification, classical-chinese, calligraphy

[image: Character-Damo 2][image: Bodhidharma Damo Daruma strong text]

Can anyone help with translating this? I think I see characters for Buddha, Chan Zen and Insight or Seeing Clearly?

Comment: thank you to the monitor for the edit especially so fast :) Very new to this but I really like the site!

Comment: Three smaller characters are not clear. Can you post a better photo, just with the characters?

Comment: Hi Andriy! Yes thank you! (xie xie nin!) This one maybe ok?

Answer (score 1):

The calligraphy seems identify two namings(both should be male names): 張果(right column), 朱自然(left column)
But I didn't found any related information or related about Zen for these namings from Google.

Comment: Xie xie nin Conifers! I have been off line for a while but thank you so much for answering! Semi cursive is a big challenge for me so I guess I need more practice for sure! I think my mind made a zen connection as the painting is supposed to be of Bodhidharma 碧眼胡 / Damo 達摩 / Daruma (I don't know the Japanese) but the name you show characters for is for one of the Taoist Immortals so very strange painting lol Thanks again!

Comment: @Qidjm Daruma is 達磨, check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daruma_doll. 
Sorry I didn't notice that it might be related to Tao, but you could still accept this answer :P